# How to enable qtranslator plugin work for custom post metabox(s)

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, qtranslate

I am trying to enable the qtranslator multilingual plugin working for custom post type's metaboxes. I am not being able to do it.

Please guide me so that the (admin interface) custom metabox(s) be split like default title and description fields.

Comment: Though its late, this question was answered against another similar question [How-can-I-modify-my-custom-widgets-to-support-qtranslate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303711/how-can-i-modify-my-custom-widgets-to-support-qtranslate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modify my custom widgets to support qtranslate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303711/how-can-i-modify-my-custom-widgets-to-support-qtranslate)

Answer (score 0):

Usually qTranslate allows you putting tags to separate languages, wherever the fields are not splitted. Have you tried doing like this?

```
<!--:en-->english text<!--:--><!--:cn-->chinese text<!--:-->
```