# How to make qTranslate supports Custom Fileds or Meta Box?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, qtranslate

I am developing a multilingual website and this site is build with many custom post types and custom fields, I'm using Meta Box and qTranslate, but it didn't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modify my custom widgets to support qtranslate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303711/how-can-i-modify-my-custom-widgets-to-support-qtranslate)

Answer (score 0):

Try word press plugin [ACF q Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-qtranslate/) which support multilingual custom field with provides compatible field types for Text, Text Area, WYSIWYG, Image and File.