# Use qTranslate on custom fields in customize.php

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

Is there any way I can make it to work with WordPress's customize.php (for the custom input fields) in my template?

Right now it look like this:
http://2.1m.yt/ZWxITnN.png

I don't have any blue border here, how do I get that to work?
Appearance -> Customize

Please help me!

Comment: Your question is unclear. I think you want to add new field under Wordpress customize.php If yes, then you can use Wordpress Theme Customizer API

Comment: Hi - sorry for that, but right now I'm using qTranslate for my custom theme. When I'm edit a page, every single input fields, has a blue border to the left, that indicates that it can be translate to multiple languages - but when I'm in the appearance-> customize page, I can't see a border on the fields. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please re-edit the question for better understanding of the issue you are facing.

Comment: Sorry - I'm on a mobile and when I've was pressing return (for makeing the line break, it just post my comment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modify my custom widgets to support qtranslate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303711/how-can-i-modify-my-custom-widgets-to-support-qtranslate)

Answer (score 0):

I think the translation using qTranslate plugin doesn't support Appearance > Customize. This will be a limitation to a free plugin. You must try asking the same question to plugin author in Wordpress Support Forum.

Hope Plugin Author can help!

Comment: I already did that, but no answer. I was hoping that somebody in here, could help. As I'm reading it, there is some kind of a i18-ish json file that I should create and tell to point at the fields in the customization- but I'm not sure how to get it to work.